# Не работает плагин Sticky Foundation в mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, css, foundation

Не работает плагин Sticky Foundation в mozilla. В консоли ошибок нет, все подключено. Windows 10, Firefox 62.0.3
Почему и  как исправить?

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```css
.x-header {
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
.x-nav__sticky {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
.x-content {
  height: 150vh;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.0-rc.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.0-rc.3/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="x-layout">
  <div class="x-header" id="jsHeader"></div>
  <div class="x-nav" data-sticky-container>
    <div class="x-nav__sticky sticky" data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;stickyOn:small;"
data-top-anchor="jsHeader:bottom">
      Sticky
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="x-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus perferendis laboriosam aut fuga voluptatum molestias ullam, enim impedit quia sed neque reiciendis pariatur quis porro, animi laudantium amet fugiat id!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus perferendis laboriosam aut fuga voluptatum molestias ullam, enim impedit quia sed neque reiciendis pariatur quis porro, animi laudantium amet fugiat id!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus perferendis laboriosam aut fuga voluptatum molestias ullam, enim impedit quia sed neque reiciendis pariatur quis porro, animi laudantium amet fugiat id!</p>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus perferendis laboriosam aut fuga voluptatum molestias ullam, enim impedit quia sed neque reiciendis pariatur quis porro, animi laudantium amet fugiat id!</p>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus perferendis laboriosam aut fuga voluptatum molestias ullam, enim impedit quia sed neque reiciendis pariatur quis porro, animi laudantium amet fugiat id!</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: работает же у меня все ок .

Comment: я конечно извеняюсь - а просто классический sticky на jquery не вариант ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в свойстве `stikyOn: small`, `js` не может правильно отработать с этим значением.
Foundation использует класс `foundation-mq` для передачи `breakpoints` в `js`.

```
font-family: "small=0em&medium=48em&large=64em&xlarge=75em";
```

На ПК версии `Firefox` при получение данных значений через

`$('.foundation-mq').css('font-family')`

возвращает

```
"serif, \"small=0em&medium=48em&large=64em&xlarge=75em\""
```

После, когда js обрабатывает строку, он создает значение не `small`, а `erif, /"small"`, что приводит к проблемам.

На данный момент, что бы исправить данный баг я добавил к `breakpoints` перед `small` точку `xs: 0`, теперь неправильное название у этой точки, а `small` работает.

Answer (score 0):

Может я чего то не понимаю, но уже давно имеется и поддерживается всеми браузерами

```
position: sticky
```

в css. Зачем для такой простой задачи использовать js?

Comment: Как минимум это поддержка браузерами, к тому же нужно что бы sticky срабатывал в определенный момент